# Chebyshev's first function prime count

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

How is Chebyshev's first function $$\vartheta(N)=\sum_{p\leq N}\log p$$ useful in counting primes? Can it alone be used to analytically derive the prime number theorem?

Answer (score 2):

The function $\sum \log p$ is useful for counting primes because it only increases at primes. This property is used for example in Bertrand's theorem, the idea being roughly that if $\vartheta(2x)>\vartheta(x)$ then there must be a prime between $x$ and $2x.$

Proofs of the PNT tend to be variations on the analytic proofs of Hadamard/de la Vallee Poussin or the "elementary" proof of Selberg/Erdős. There may be other proofs but I doubt any proof can be said to rely solely on use of $\vartheta(x).$

Harold Edwards in *Riemann's Zeta Function* gives the proofs of both Hadamard and de la Vallee Poussin. G.J.O. Jameson gives Selberg/Erdős' "elementary" proof in Chapter 6 and two analytic proofs in Chapter 3 of *The Prime Number Theorem.* Ingham presents an analytic proof at p. 26 of *The Distribution of Prime Numbers.* Apostol in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory gives an analytic proof in Chapter 13. Davenport in *Multiplicative Number Theory* at page 111 also offers a version of the classic proof.

> **All of these proofs involve the log-prime counting function $\psi(x)$** but of course $\psi(x)$ can be expressed in terms of $\vartheta(x).$

Can $\vartheta(x)$ be used alone to derive the PNT? Hopefully the references here would allow you decide whether or not $\psi(x)$ (and implicitly $\vartheta(x)$) meet your criteria for being used alone.

Comment: Nice write. Just curious on whether it would be possible these days to give a page proof of the prime number theorem?

Comment: Where can one find the proof of prime between $x$ and $2x$ from jump in $\vartheta(x)$? that is an interesting proof.

Comment: @Turbo: Depends on the reader's background...and the font size. The proof of Bertrand is in Ramanujan's Collected Works. Can't give you an exact cite but I think you can find it from that.

Comment: Here is Ramanujan's proof that does not use Stirling's formula: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/Meher-Murty-Monthly.pdf  Here is a proof that uses Stirling's formula: http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html

Answer (score 2):

You can see directly the relationship using partial summation. In fact, you have $$\underset{p\leq x}{\sum}\log\left(p\right)=\pi\left(x\right)\log\left(x\right)-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi\left(t\right)}{t}dt$$ where $\pi\left(*\right)$ is the prime counting function.